# mutate Rails form based on which page user comes from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Meeting model, which can be initiated in a couple ways. An user can go to a page and initialize a meeting as Tutor. He can also initiate a meeting from another page as a Student. I would like to have a common form for event. If it is initiated as Tutor, then certain fields will be automatically filled out, thus there's no need to show these fields in the form. Similar situation for meeting initiated by Student.

How can I change the form depending on page user comes from? I would prefer not to use Javascript if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be nested routes. You don't really describe the relationship between your models, but the idea would be to have 2 different URLs, like this:

```
example.com/students/3/meetings/new
example.com/tutors/7/meetings/new
```

Your meetings_controller can check for the presence of `params[:student_id]` or `params[:tutor_id]` to determine which kind of form it will be displaying.

If the user is actually *logged in* as either a Student or a Tutor, then you should probably be using that information (perhaps from a cookie) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a more systematic solution to me, but I am not exactly sure the benefit over Jonathan's solution. Could you educate me on that?

Comment: Depending on your app and the models' relationships, this might be a more elegant solution. It all depends.

Comment: Well, for your specific case, the only benefit is a slightly prettier URL -- `/students/3/meetings/new` vs `/meetings/new?type=student` or something. What would push me toward nested routes is if down the road you might support a URL like `/students/3/meetings` to list all meetings for a given student, for example. Otherwise, they are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Thank you both, Elliot and Jonathan. Your answers are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass data to be pre-filled on the request line. Or in the events_controller, you can check the HTTP_REFERRER and set attributes as needed.

Passing data on the request line is probably the better choice, but it all depends on the details of your app.

An example:

```
<%= link_to edit_event_path(@event, :name => 'Override Name', :day => 'Monday') %>
# will generate /events/123/edit?name=Override%20Name&day=Monday
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Could you please give me an example of passing data on the request line? Thanks a lot for your help.